# Netbeans Docker service credential exception

Tags: windows, docker, netbeans-8.2

Docker credentials store support having conflict with NetBeans application vs CLI/Windows Docker application.

User will get below the exception trace response in NetBeans.

```
Stacktrace: 
java.lang.NullPointerException
   at java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode(Base64.java:549)
   at org.netbeans.modules.docker.DockerConfig.createCredentials(DockerConfig.java:321)
   at org.netbeans.modules.docker.DockerConfig.getAllCredentials(DockerConfig.java:127)
   at org.netbeans.modules.docker.api.CredentialsManager.getAllCredentials(CredentialsManager.java:66)
   at org.netbeans.modules.docker.ui.credentials.CredentialsListPanel.<init>(CredentialsListPanel.java:70)
   at org.netbeans.modules.docker.ui.credentials.CredentialsAction.actionPerformed(CredentialsAction.java:73)
```

This conflict related with credential store, which CLI/Windows support 'wincred' the same way NetBeans support 'auth token'. Here both application tools use the same 'config.json' file at your user workspace under the '.docker/' folder.

If NetBeans Docker service is the primary use then current workaround will be, delete existing content in 'config.json' file if you already setup. then try to add "credentials" in NetBeans, Docker service.

Comment: I deleted the contents of the file as recommended, did not work for me (get an NPE when creating credentials in docker service in netbeans)